# videogular not loading any videos or controls

Tags: angularjs, videogular

I'm implementing videogular in my angular application, which is my first angular website. I've followed everything as shown in the example http://www.videogular.com/tutorials/how-to-start/, but nothing is coming up on the UI and didn't find any errors in the console. (I've installed videogular using nugget package manager).

Controller Code:

```
 $scope.config = {
 sources: [
 { src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4"), type: "video/mp4" },
 { src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.webm"), type: "video/webm" },
 { src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.ogg"), type: "video/ogg" }
 ],
 tracks: [
 {
 src: "http://www.videogular.com/assets/subs/pale-blue-dot.vtt",
 kind: "subtitles",
 srclang: "en",
 label: "English",
 default: ""
 }
 ],
 theme: "~/Content/videogular.css",
 plugins: {
 poster: "http://www.videogular.com/assets/images/videogular.png"
 }
 };
```

HTML View:

```
<div class="videogular-container">
                            <videogular vg-theme="http://www.videogular.com/styles/themes/default/latest/videogular.css">
                                <vg-media vg-src="config.sources"></vg-media>
                               <vg-controls>
                                    <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
                                    <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
                                    <vg-scrub-bar>
                                        <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
                                    </vg-scrub-bar>
                                    <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
                                    <vg-volume>
                                        <vg-mute-button></vg-mute-button>
                                        <vg-volume-bar></vg-volume-bar>
                                    </vg-volume>
                                    <vg-fullscreen-button></vg-fullscreen-button>
                                </vg-controls>
                               <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
                                <vg-poster vg-url='config.plugins.poster'></vg-poster>
                            </videogular>
</div>
```

Dependencies Added:

'ngSanitize', 'com.2fdevs.videogular', 'com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls','com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay','com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster'

Please tell me what is wrong here

Comment: Is the controller code getting called?

Comment: have you added `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to your html?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://www.videogular.com/docs/#/api/com.2fdevs.videogular.directive:videogular) `vg-theme` is expecting a scope name variable but you are passing a string literal.

> vgTheme   string
>   String with a scope name variable. This directive will inject a CSS link in the header of your page. This parameter is required.

Change it to use the `config.theme` (make sure your $scope.theme path is the correct one)

**UPDATE**: vg-media also need to specify vg-tracks like this

```
<vg-media vg-src="controller.config.sources"
                  vg-tracks="controller.config.tracks">
        </vg-media>
```

Could you double check if you are providing all the required inputs to videogular directive?

Comment: I've tried this, but still no luck, I could see an empty container at least now, which was not happening earlier and here I guess the video is loaded, but no controls are showing up. I was trying to debug through the controls directive and at this line of code $scope.currentIcon = $.parseHTML($scope.vgPlayIcon)[0].data; I see that playIcon object as undefined and for the time it is just display as '{current}' in the middle of the video. Could you please help on this.

Comment: as per the documentation vg-tracks is an optional directive                  vgTracks :
directive in module com.2fdevs.videogular
Description :
Optional directive for vg-media to add a list of tracks.

vgTracks Bindable array with a list of subtitles sources. A track source is an object with five properties: src, kind, srclang, label and default.

Comment: Can you update your question with your latest code? Also try removing all the vg-controls and vg-overlay directives and se if the simplest videogular loads.

Comment: thank you guys I got the help from dev team and I'm able to get see the videos coming up. I was asked to upgrade to videogular 1.2.1